# How to get VC compiler version from PE file programmatically?

Tags: visual-c++, portable-executable

The [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) is able to detect the VC complier version from PE file.
it shows "Microsoft Visual C++ 8" for my exe file which is statically linked to libCMT(no dll dependency).

How is that done?  It must replies on some structure in PE file which is unknown to me.

**UPDATE:**

1. CFF Explorer can get the correct VC complier version for a statically linked PE file (no DLL dependency to msvcmXX.dll, msvcpXX.dll or msvcrXX.dll)
2. Even I cleared the LinkerVersion / ImageVersion / SubsytstemVersion / OperratingSystemVersion fields in PE optional header to ZERO, CFF explorer still can know the correct VC compiler version.

Seems CFF explorer is using a much reliable way to detect VC compiler version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PE Header have some info about linker(or compiler). Check out:

http://wiki.osdev.org/PE

and also:

http://mirror.sweon.net/madchat/vxdevl/papers/winsys/pefile/pefile.htm

The magic word in the PE header maybe the key to your answer.

*edit*:

Seems CFF explorer rely on the code signature. I've found some interesting post here:

[Determining Which Compiler Built a Win32 PE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764329/determining-which-compiler-built-a-win32-pe)

In RBerteig's reply, the internal symbols can be used to determine compiler.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24417/Portable-Executable-P-E-Code-Injection-Injecting-a

From this post, the _main address is one of the signature to determine it.

and this post: http://ntcore.com/files/richsign.htm

give more clue about Microsoft compiler signature.

Comment: CFF Explorer does not rely on MajorLinkerVersion / MiniLinkerVersion. I tried to clear these fields to ZERO, then open the PE file again with CFF Explorer,  it can still get the correct compiler and shown in "File Info".

Comment: @user325320 Search with compiler signature and you'll get some interesting result:)

Comment: Thanks, I reset the rich signature part to zero and it still can get correct version number. quite amazing, I will send an email to the author for this, hope he can get back to me

Comment: For me CFF Explorer and PE Detective don't work, they always report that the compiler has been Microsft Visual C++ 8.0 even if Intel, Mingw64 or any other was used instead.  Is there any other better tool?  Regards.